# Ubuntu Studio 21.04 does not complete installation

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-studio, 21.04, zram

Have downloaded ubuntustudio-21.04-dvd-amd64.iso
SHA265 checksum is ok.
Wrote .iso to USB stick (have tried three different types by now).

Booted Dell Latitude E7440 from it. Chose "install" from desktop. Installation routine starts, asks the standard questions etc. Then, in a late phase it stops with:

Installation Failed
Boost.Python error in job "packages".

Command '`apt-get --purge -q -y remove live-* calamares-settings-ubuntustudio calamares hunspell-en-us zram-config cifs-utils`' returned non-zero exit status 100.

```
{...}
Unable to locate package zram-config
```

See attached screenshot.
Any hints how to fix this?
Thanks, Andreas.

[image]

Comment: There is a reason why you are wishing to use ubuntu-studio, of course... perhaps you might share that in an [edit]

Comment: Some details on what type of installation you made, was it an Erase Disk and install, Install Alongside, Manual Partitioning etc.. Created or re-used partitions etc...    I've found `calamares` a little fragile (with manual) so when I have trouble, my fall back is to prepare my disk before hand and have the installer just use the prepared partition(s) for manual partitioning options.. but you've not given what you used.